# React - Add padStart() to {this.value} - possible in mustache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add string.padStart(2, "0") to minutes and seconds.

```
return(
        <li key={id}><span onClick={() => handleRemoveStage(id)}>{todo.duration.hours}:{todo.duration.minutes}:{todo.duration.seconds}</li>
    )
```

It is possible inline like in Vue? Eventually, how do to this otherwise in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use any JavaScript expression inside `{...}` in JSX. So yes, if `todo.duration.hours` is a string, you can just do `todo.duration.hours.padStart(...)`. Have you tried that before you asked?

Comment: Ok, I've forgotten to notice I had "padStart is not a function", but it was because "minutes" was type Number, not String... Sorry for opening topic.